# Null Value in songArrayAdapter

Tags: android

```
s1="http://newmp3mad.com/128-734892s/Manali%20Trance.mp3";
        s2="http://d.djtune.net/data/96/Sajan_Main_Haari-Harshdeep_Kaur%5Bwww.Mp3MaD.Com%5D.mp3";
        s3="http://d.djtune.net/dataa/731660a/Sawan_Aaya_Hai_(Creature_3D)-Arijit_Singh%5Bwww.Mp3MaD.Com%5D.mp3";
        s4="http://d.djtune.net/dataa/45695/Chittiyaan_Kalaiyaan-Meet_Bros_Anjan_Ankit%5Bwww.Mp3MaD.Com%5D.mp3";
        s5="http://d.djtune.net/dataa/736379u/Saanson_Ko-Arijit_Singh%5Bwww.Mp3MaD.Com%5D.mp3";
       String[]songUrllist={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5};

    playpauseButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
    songSeekBar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    String[]songNamelist={"Manali Trance","Sajan Main Haari","Saawan Aaya Hai","Chittiyaan Kalaiyaan","Saanson Ko"};
    songArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        urlHashMap=new HashMap<>();
        urlHashMap.put("URL",songUrllist[i]);
        urlHashMap.put("NAME",songNamelist[i]);
        songArrayList.add(urlHashMap);
    }
    songArrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,songArrayList);
    songSpinner.setAdapter(songArrayAdapter);
    songSpinner.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Comment: I am not sure but first of all be sure if your songUrllist is not null

Comment: Hardi patel: I declared String s1,s2,s3,s4,s5 & in that I entered the url of each songs in respective strings, so there are 5 url of songs and then i made array of string.... string[] songUrllist={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using a `List<String>` as input data to the `ArrayAdapter`. The basic `ArrayAdapter` has no way of handling your list of `HashMap<>` You need to extend the `ArrayAdapter` with a own class that handles your specific data.

Nathan has written a good example on [Using an ArrayAdapter with ListView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView)